# What to set for st_nlink as attribute when implementing FUSE?

Tags: linux, fs, fuse

When implementing FUSE library, attributes for the directories should be defined by getattr() callback.

But what to set for this st_nlink?

In this example, they set it to 2, but I don't know the exact reason.

https://github.com/lxc/lxcfs/blob/2ed933d959f54bee70985e260660a468ef9d21a1/src/proc_fuse.c#L87

What is st_nlink for? And should it be 1 or 2 as default for my user-space FUSE directories?

For example, if I define a directory called "/dev", and there are ".", ".." and "snd" sub-entries in it, should the st_nlink for "/dev" be 2?
Because the hard link (entry) are /dev/snd and /dev/snd/./

Answer (score 2):

Interesting, I did read the following.

> st_nlink is the number of hard links to the file. This count keeps track
>   of how many directories have entries for this file. If the count is
>   ever decremented to zero, then the file itself is discarded as soon as
>   no process still holds it open. Symbolic links are not counted in the
>   total.

https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Attribute-Meanings.html

I assume the "file" is being used twice, and there for it's st_nlink is being set to two.

I also assume it is used for a reface counting design 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_counting

Comment: Thank you John. The point is I should set st_nlink value for the directories in the getattr() callback in fuse lib.  So my understanding is, if I am not going to implement the hard link in the fuse, then the st_nlink is meaningless, or useless, so I can set it as any value.  If the hard link is supported in my fuse, then st_nlink  should be calculated every time it enters the getattr() callback, not just a fixed value.